# Create Dynamic databound control in acumatica

Tags: dynamic, controls, acumatica

How to create dynamic controls in **acumatica**? Anyone tried it? 
I didnt see any sample before to do this, so i am not clear on how to approach this.

I will have the data from a table for the controls to be generated, and according to that data i need to generate controls [textbox or a label]  dynamically in **acumatica** page. If anyone know the way to approach this, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a coding service, do some googling and try it on your own, when you face an issue then post it here.

Comment: maybe you can use FieldSelecting, I'm working on an example for you, be patient.

Comment: What you are looking for is probably changing the FieldState in FieldSelecting. I'd suggest you go take a look at the doc under **Acumatica Framework > API Reference > Event Model > Events > FieldSelecting Event** as well as the section under **FieldSelecting Event** named **PXFieldState**.